# IPtables as a reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm playing with iptables and trying to do quite simple task: forward traffic to port 8888 on my Ubuntu to another server located at IP 172.21.16.1 and port 5000.

In my environment I have a windows workstation. Ubuntu served by hyper-v. My windows workstation has several network interfaces including created by hyper-v. There the IP address assigned to `172.21.16.1`. The Ubuntu has an IP `172.21.26.237`.

I started simple web server on the windows workstation which listens the port 5000 for HTTP requests. If a open page http://172.21.16.1:5000 in Browser (does not matter, if it Ubuntu or Windows) I see expected output.

I checked several articles and it looks like it should be easy and straightforward. I executed the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.16.1:5000
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 8888 -j SNAT --to-source 172.21.26.237
```

If I open the page http://172.21.26.237:8888/ from my Windows workstation - timeout.

What I've checked:

(1) `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` returns `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

(2) iptable-save gives the following content:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 19 20:15:37 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1066:122755]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [90:4680]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [255:18156]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 19 20:15:37 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 19 20:15:37 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [233:25903]
:INPUT ACCEPT [198:18944]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23:1798]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [41:2734]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.16.1:5000
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j SNAT --to-source 172.21.26.237
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 19 20:15:37 2020
```

(3) Traces from `tcpdump ..... port 8888`:

```
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
22:18:38.078418 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 35408, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63351 > 172.21.26.237.8888: Flags [S], cksum 0xa604 (correct), seq 2988342963, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:18:38.078566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 35409, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63352 > 172.21.26.237.8888: Flags [S], cksum 0x04c0 (correct), seq 3168343356, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:18:38.329143 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 35410, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63353 > 172.21.26.237.8888: Flags [S], cksum 0x58e7 (correct), seq 371877827, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:18:39.084897 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 35411, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
```

(4) Traces from `tcpdump ..... port 5000`:

```
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
22:19:34.468908 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 35424, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63367 > 172.21.16.1.5000: Flags [S], cksum 0x09ca (correct), seq 3528594630, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:19:34.468992 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 35425, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63368 > 172.21.16.1.5000: Flags [S], cksum 0x3138 (correct), seq 561028665, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:19:34.729633 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 35426, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.21.16.1.63369 > 172.21.16.1.5000: Flags [S], cksum 0xc4c0 (correct), seq 920253766, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:19:35.473332 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 35428, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
```

(5) And here is also output from `curl -v url:8888` executed on windows:

```
> curl -v 172.21.26.237:8888
* Rebuilt URL to: 172.21.26.237:8888/
*   Trying 172.21.26.237...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.21.26.237 port 8888 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to 172.21.26.237 port 8888: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.21.26.237 port 8888: Timed out
```

Unfortunately, still have no clue.

Comment: Please edit to include `tcpdump ..... port 5000` from ubuntu and `curl -v url:8888` from Windows.

Comment: @kubanczyk, did as you suggested, still no clue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, making the question better is of course important. It will be also nice to get a move to a solution. Could you please explain, why removing ```q``` gives anything helpful?

Comment: Because `-q` removes critical information about the packets. I'm not even sure why this option exists; the only thing it does is to make the output useless.

Comment: Wait a minute. It looks like you're trying to DNAT back to the same machine you're connecting from! What is going on here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, as I said at the very beginning of my question, I'm **playing** with iptables and trying to make simple scenario working. Of course I can use another (3rd machine), but it should work also with two machines I guess. Just tried 3rd workstation, no changes.

Comment: That's hardly a simple scenario! It's pretty much an impossible one, really. You should first try a more realistic setup. You aren't going to DNAT back to yourself in any reasonable setup.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, in plaground we all often have scenarios which do not make any sense in production. Anyway, it works after the fix suggested by kubanczyk. I screwed up with my SNAT configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNAT looks good, but SNAT I think I'd go

```
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j SNAT --to-source 172.21.26.237
```

instead of

```
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j SNAT --to-source 172.21.26.237
```

I mean since PREROUTING changes the port from 8888 to 5000, it doesn't make sense to expect 8888 anywhere behind that stage.